# how to add Two TextView in Android's ViewPagerExtension Library

Tags: android

I am using [ViewPagerExtension](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions)
in my android project.I am able to add one textview for each tab. I want to add two textviews in each tabs.How can i achieae that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a wrapper view, i.e. `LinearLayout`, and put those two `TextView` elements inside the wrapper view. Then, instead of adding `TextView` elements to `ViewPager`, add wrapper layouts to the `ViewPager`.